# JSON is not getting validated based on schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I must be missing something here, but the below JSON is not getting validated against the schema. 
For example, the required attribute from the Java/JavaScript object is never getting enforced as per the schema. (FYI- Every language object may have other attributes or nested object)

However, if I completely remove the definition and directly put under array items each separately, then it validates.

I want to use 'definitions' and gets validated.The reason I have to put all the object in definitions and later I may have to put different language object in oneOf/allOf for other certain validation check.

Online check:
[Schema and JSON](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVBQCe1XCTIsARo1yYKGrWX64AjgFcAlnZFGA2je0gANoXhBR0JBXDBUGwBdTSQyan4WA34KZzCjOFiff0Dg0PCoRAzkYrI9AyNUQn5xXWtM4tR8Z3gASQoCfNIARhiSn2d2-E7C7z6dfUMC1FNzSwj65ABfXrGQAN0AeQlPUZKivpLUNDttqZAVUVwJZoHnNjA6AClCADdiEF3i5c-kfYOfY5XCrnS7XeC3e5PV6EADKmH4zmoVg+Cy+n0io0WNm+sVQIiuNxS93So1QzzeJNRqDsTlcuHcBS8qJ8FHEzVw-HmB2in1Q8USHJSaQKf1W2UElP+DRAuHgjnwO2Zq3J7x+xQxSpxUp0bPgHMlUtKE2BYFZzQlKKlWNR1pKWulKrhCKRBsOIBpLjciu1MvgCV8vnpdR90Oc-hMga5fR5VJA-KSQuGord4td-1Qsvl3sNPkd8MRyLVyA1VpWBwzfpYAaDIqLRvKZ1NCMCUYO9vLazeYcIEcmpGTqzKfbITfNrb6tonmOxCEWIHUIGcUBgNlQ4tywtITL2vL8AQtpDJ0ODg91+rOAAVcO1OZavmWRrHU2c887kQ+fLL-YGGYeQAAWAAmE83VDcNIzOABWcdJw1OdFiAA)

JSON

```
{
  "languages": [
    {
      "lang": "Java",
      "trainer": "Peter"
    },
    {
      "lang": "JavaScript",
      "enrolled": "42",
      "available": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "languages"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "languages": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Java"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/JavaScript"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Java": {
      "required": [
        "trainer"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "lang": {
          "enum": [
            "Java"
          ]
        },
        "trainer": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "JavaScript": {
      "required": [
        "enrolled",
        "available"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "lang": {
          "enum": [
            "JavaScript"
          ]
        },
        "enrolled": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "available": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The fixed schema and it works now

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "languages"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "languages": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Java"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/JavaScript"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Java": {
      "required": [
        "trainer"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "lang": {
          "enum": [
            "Java"
          ]
        },
        "trainer": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "JavaScript": {
      "required": [
        "enrolled",
        "available"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "lang": {
          "enum": [
            "JavaScript"
          ]
        },
        "enrolled": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "available": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like author missing into json

Comment: @VelikiiNehochuha Thanks for pointing out. I have fixed the schema. But still it wont validate

Comment: Added the online link to see things in action in the above question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the "array" definition is not correct. The objects that can be added in the array must be refereed in the "items", after you define the type of the items. Something like this:

```
"languages": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "anyOf": [
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/Java"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/JavaScript"}
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed myself

What I did: I have placed the json object blocks under items section of array.

Comment: Consider either explaining the fix to the problem or deleting your question =]